# Find size of maximum connected region in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, depth-first-search, region, connected-components

So I have a matrix (n row by m column) and want to find the region with the most connected "1s". For example if I have the following matrix:

```
1 1 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0
```

There are 2 regions of "1s" in the matrix.

1st region:

```
1 1
  1 1
    1
```

2nd region:

```
1
```

I would like to create an algorithm that will output the maximum = 5. I think this has something to do with Depth First Search but I only have base R and access to a few packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `SDMTools`. First, we convert the matrix into `raster`, then we detect `clump`s (patches) of connected cells. Each clump gets a unique ID. NA and zero are used as background values. Finally, `PatchStat` provides statistics for each patch.

```
library(raster)
library(SDMTools)

r <- raster(mat)    
rc <- clump(r)
as.matrix(rc)
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
> [1,]   NA    1    1    1    1
> [2,]    1   NA   NA    1   NA
> [3,]    1    1    1   NA    1
> [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
> [5,]    2    2   NA   NA   NA
> ```

```
p <- PatchStat(rc)
max(p$n.cell)
```

> `[1] 10`

**Sample data**

```
set.seed(2)
m <- 5
n <- 5
mat <- round(matrix(runif(m * n), m, n))
mat
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
> [1,]    0    1    1    1    1
> [2,]    1    0    0    1    0
> [3,]    1    1    1    0    1
> [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
> [5,]    1    1    0    0    0
> ```

Comment: That is a sexy way. Even if clump sounds not so sexy. So much in R!
Sadly I would like to do this without requiring those packages, or most really. Any ideas? I mean obviously I attempted it with a list containing each of the connected 1s. But that's about as far as I got.

Comment: If you want to compute it from scratch, you could dig into the source code of `clump` function (https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/master/R/clump.R). But it uses `adjacent` and `clusters` that comes from  `raster` and `igraph` packages...

Comment: True, I know igraph is important here. Oh well I will keep at it and try some tricks. I mean I can get all the elements closest to each 1 in a list, very simple. Now I just have to merge that list into separate vectors that contain the unique connected points. Hmm... But thank you for your input!

Comment: Turns out igraph is available.  `raster` is our downfall :(

Comment: If you already have the adjacent points then you only need to use this line `igraph::clusters(igraph::graph(adjv, directed=FALSE))$membership[val]` from `clump` source code. `adjv` is a vector with all connected cells (in my example `9  3 12  6 15  9  3  2  4  3  5  4 12 11 13 12 22 21  2  6  5  9  9 13  6  2  9  5 13  9  2  3  3  4  4  5 11 12 12 13 21 22  3  9  6 12  9 15  9  4 11  6  4  9  6 11`) and `val` is a vector with the cells with 1 (in my example `2  3  4  5  6  9 11 12 13 15 21 22`). This will give you a different value for each patch.

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm. Just needs a little smoothing for interpretability!

Comment: @TonyHellmuth: if you preferred it be done without other packages, should edit that into the question. Is there a reason, or just curiosity?

Comment: Oh it's just  require admin rights to download packages. I guess curiosity is the major player now :). I did say only a few packages; maybe I should be slightly clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I did this eventually with use of `igraph`:

```
library(igraph)
data<-scan("stdin")
n<-data[1]
m<-data[2]

mat<-matrix(data[3:(n*m+2)],nrow=n,ncol=m,byrow=TRUE)
labels <- as.vector(mat)
rows <- (seq(length(labels)) - 1) %% nrow(mat)
cols <- ceiling(seq(length(labels)) / nrow(mat))
g <- graph.lattice(dim(mat), nei=2)

# Remove edges between elements of different types or that aren't diagonal
edgelist <- get.edgelist(g)
retain <- labels[edgelist[,1]] == labels[edgelist[,2]] &
  abs(rows[edgelist[,1]] - rows[edgelist[,2]]) <= 1 &
  abs(cols[edgelist[,1]] - cols[edgelist[,2]]) <= 1
g <- delete.edges(g, E(g)[!retain])

y<-clusters(g)$membership ### clustered matrix as vector
m<-as.vector(mat) ### original matrix 
z<-y[m>0] ### ignore where original matrix is 0
cat(sort(table(z),decreasing=TRUE)[[1]])
```