# Remove small shapes from BW image in R

Tags: r, image

I'm trying to perform some cleaning operations in R on black and white images. In particular, I need to remove small white shapes, keeping only the greatest one ([see a test image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24w82.png))

It seems an easy task but I got stuck on this step, even trying many dedicated packages. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828805/find-size-of-maximum-connected-region-in-matrix

Comment: Thanks @AndrewGustar! It seems perfect. However I'm wondering how to automatically detect the greatest shape. Is it always that one with clump label = 1?

Comment: No, but if you have a look at the documentation for `raster::clump` and run the example at the end, it will show you how to find the largest one.